# Finding specific links with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using Beautiful Soup for Python to parse a webpage in order to download data from certain files and aggregate them into one file. The webpages I'm parsing contain tons of different download links, and I'm having trouble getting the specific links that I want.

The HTML is essentially set up like this:

```
<li> <b>data I dont care about: </b>
<a href ="/id#____dontcare2010">2010</a> <a href = "/id#____dontcare2011">2011</a> (and so on)
</li>

<li> <b>data I DO care about: </b>
< a href ="/id#___data2010">2010</a> <a href= "/id#____data2011">2011</a> ....
</li>
```

(the id#____ is just an id number for the specific object that that webpage contains information on, not too important for the question but I figured I'd get as accurate as possible)

What I want is for BeautifulSoup to find the list ("`<li>`" tags) that contains the String "Links I DO care about: " and then store every link in that list into a Python list. I've tried,

```
soup.findAll('li', text = 'Links I DO care about: ")
```

but that doesn't seem to work...

I would imagine there's some way to do these steps with Beautiful Soup:
1. find specific list that I want
2. find all the `<a href="..."></a>`tags in that list
3. store all those links in a Python list.

I can't seem to find a way to do this though.

Any advice?

Comment: You must be having certain specific links that you would be expecting. So, why not use regex and filter out those urls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `text` argument (which is now called `string`) would not search inside the children elements texts of an element (why? - see the last note inside this [documentation paragraph](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string), `.string` would be effectively `None` for each of the presented `li` elements). What I would do is to locate the `b` element by text, then get all the `a` [siblings](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling):

```
b = soup.find("b", text=lambda text: text and "data I DO care about:" in text)
links = [a["href"] for a in b.find_next_siblings("a", href=True)]
print(links)
```

Or, you can [go up the tree](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-parents-and-find-parent) from `b` to `li` and then use `find_all()` to find all links inside `li`:

```
b = soup.find("b", text=lambda text: text and "data I DO care about:" in text)
li = b.find_parent("li")
links = [a["href"] for a in li.find_all("a", href=True)]
print(links)
```

There are, of course, other ways to locate the desired `a` elements.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `text=lambda text: text and "data I DO care about:" in text` ?